# Crystal Reports: Refresh Dynamic Parameters in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, parameters, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using Crystal Reports 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0 framework) to build an ASP.NET web application to display Crystal Reports files through a "CrystalReportsViewer" web control. My application changes the data source of the report at runtime based on a configuration file.

Some of the reports I use have dynamic parameters that pull values from a database table. When I run the Crystal Report, it populates the parameter listbox and allows the user to choose one or many of them. When I run the report in the CrystalReportsViewer control on the ASP.NET page, it gives me an empty text box where the parameters list used to be.

Is there a way that I can 'refresh' or re-populate the dynamic parameters?

Thanks in advance,

-Steven

Answer (score 0):

I've always had trouble with dynamic parameters. I don't use Crystal in the exact same way you are, but I've noticed that when my data comes from a Stored Procedure, the dynamic parameters are empty when I run the report. My workaround is to set the paramters to null when running the report and then clicking OK on the parameter screen. At that point crystal refreshes the parameters list and them I'm presented with the values in the db to select from. Dynamic parameters work well for me when I add the data tables directly to the report instead of using a stored procedure.

I don't know if this really answers your question but I hope it helps.